# How soon does nginx's token bucket replenish when limiting at requests per minute?

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

We've decided that we want to experiment and limit requests per minute instead of requests per second on our sites.  However, I am confused by the [burst parameter](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpLimitReqModule) in this context.

I am under the impression that when you use the 'nodelay' flag, the rate limiting facility acts like a [token bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) instead of a leaky bucket.  That being the case, the bucket size is equal to the burst parameter, and every time that you violate the policy (say 1 req/s), you have to put a token in the bucket.  Once the bucket is full (being equal to the burst setting), you are given a 503 error page.

I am also under the impression that once a violator stops going against the policy, a token is removed from the bucket at a rate of 1 token/s allowing him to regain access to the site.

Assuming that I have the above correct, my question is what happens when I start regulating access per minute?  If we chose 60 requests per minute, at what rate does the token bucket replenish?

Comment: While I don't intend to discourage discussion here, this technical question about nginx may obtain a more informed response by posting it to the nginx user's mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experiments it seems that per minutes is just a way to write rates that are on sub-second intervals.  So 60r/m == 1r/s.  This can be demonstrated by setting it to 60 requests per minute and then launching say 2 requests per second.  It will be limited from the start, not only after 60 requests have been made.

That being said, I still don't fully understand how this all works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does work like a token bucket algorithm. I also manually experimented with my server to verify this. You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869390/nginxngx-http-limit-req-module-for-how-long-is-503-returned-once-exceeding-the for example

If you choose 60 req/min  it will replenish one token every second.