# NGINX - throttle requests to prevent abuse

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, throttling

The reason I want to do this is because users develop against our API with JavaScript, and some developers screw up and cause visitors to slam the server with AJAX requests. When this happens, I want to be able to throttle the API requests to perhaps **50 requests per minute**, or something to that effect.

**Note:** (particularly DB intensive resources, so perhaps at a path level, rather than server-wide (e.g. throttle "/json_api/", but not "/static/").

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This can be done using the [LimitReqModule](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) with Nginx.  However if this is for a reverse proxy you might want to try out the new [rate limiting supported by HAProxy](http://blog.serverfault.com/2010/08/26/1016491873/).

I found the nginx rate limiting to be a [little bit confusing](https://serverfault.com/questions/146351/how-soon-does-nginxs-token-bucket-replenish-when-limiting-at-requests-per-minute) to get the exact rate you want.

But you basically have something like:

```
limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=default:10m   rate=50r/m;
```

in the `http` section and then something like the following in the `location` section within the `server` section:

```
limit_req zone=default burst=10 nodelay;
```

In order not to have it for a certain section like `/static` you would just make that a separate `location` and not include it the `limit_req` directive (or the inverse).

Comment: thanks. Can you explain what those things are doing (zone, burst, nodelay)? And, did you mean to put `zone=limit_req_zone`, instead?

Comment: Honestly I can't explain them that well which is why I feel it is just to confusing. Michael's explanation in the link I provided sounds like it might be feasible.  I don't believe I have any typos as far as your second question goes... The module documentation I linked to has an example that might help.

Comment: zone, burst and nodelay are documented on [the Nginx wiki page about the rate limiting module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpLimitReqModule), linked to already from the answer above.

Comment: Kyle, do you know if there is a way to combine the rate limit per location with another trigger (e.g. Authorization-Header). In my case I may want to throttle the rate of a specific user.

Comment: @Nils AFAICS you could use the `$http_authorization` variable to define a new zone where the key is such header rather than the IP address, i.e., `limit_req_zone $http_authorization zone = per_user : 10m rate =
5r/s`, and then use the `per_user` zone in the location sections where you want to do the per-user rate limiting.  Untested, I only just read the documentation and the list of nginx variables... let me know if you try this out!

Comment: @Nils you can use the map module to map any variable you want. This is used to blacklist / whitelist IPs and it should also be adaptable to your needs. Refer to http://serverfault.com/questions/177461/how-to-rate-limit-in-nginx-but-including-excluding-certain-ip-addresses/642357#642357