# Will many downloads render my server unresponsive?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting

For example if I have a web server with 512 MB of RAM and my server is for downloads, will many downloads make my server unresponsive? By **unresponsive** I mean server error 508(Resource limits has reached).

Please help, I am going to choose best hosting.

Comment: I think you'd likely get a better response to this question on serverfault which is targeted more at the sysadmin/server sizing kind of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rory-McCune is right, this question is better asked in serverfault.

However, speaking from a security point of view, you want to limit the number of requests that your server will handle, and the amount of bandwidth that each can serve (throttling), for example, the module [limit_req](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) throttles connections in NginX to [prevent abuse](https://serverfault.com/a/179650/77120).

You can also [limit the number of connections per IP with IPTables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/), which limits the effectiveness of download managers.

This error may also show up from a DoS attack (but it may also show on legitimate scenarios), so you can basically look up techniques for DOS mitigation and that will help you prevent this error.